# HP Pavillion dv6 laptop - 15 beeps on startup and a black screen?

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, post

Usual story - girlfriend's step-brother's laptop is broken. I don't know a huge amount about what occurred before it broke, but I do know the following:

- When you try to turn the laptop on, it beeps **15 times exactly**.
- The screen remains black.
- The LED on the Caps Lock key flashes continuously.
- If left on, the laptop never boots - as far as I can see.
- If left on, on a stable surface with decent ventilation for a relatively short period of time, the laptop (below keyboard, but not where the RAM/HDD are) gets very hot.

I've tried doing what most websites appear to recommend for similar problems, which is to disconnect AC and battery then hold the power button down for a minute before reconnecting the AC and trying to turn the laptop on - no difference.

I've also tried re-seating the RAM, to no avail.

Comment: How old is it? Any warranty still valid? I suspect a failed CPU fan, but don't open the case if there is any warranty left.

Comment: @dunc: This is a 3 year old post, so I assume you solved the problem or it was overtaken by events.  Can you update the post with what it turned out to be or how you resolved it (maybe post a short answer)?  Your question has gotten almost 5,500 views, so anything you can add could be useful to a lot of people.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem with a Compaq Presario CQ56. 15 beeps, 'CAPS LOCK' light flash, and blank screen.

Problem: Improperly seated keyboard cable, keyboard cable or keyboard is broken.

Solution: Make sure you tuck the cable deep into the slot for good contact.  If this doesn't work, get a new keyboard.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

That beep code means CMOS RAM checksum error. But like Dave M stated that does not match HP's beep codes. I would recommend removing the battery and power from the laptop. Then hold the power button for 15 seconds. Then reconnect the battery and power to the laptop and power it on. It the computer does the boot at this point then you will need to contact HP support. You can also use the following page to referance the flashing lights and beep codes - http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=bph07107&lc=en&cc=de&dlc=en&product=5116406

Comment: Hi Jeff, as per my post, I've tried this method but it appeared to make no difference.

Comment: It sounds like the CMOS RAM is the issue with this computer. The only wa to have it repaired is to call HP support and send the laptop in.

Answer (score 0):

15 beeps does not seem to match HP info.  Check [HP BIOS Beep codes](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=bph07107&lc=en&cc=de&dlc=en&product=5116406)
 for more info.

Have there been any chages recently?  New RAM, external devices?  Try reseating RAM as a start.

Comment: Have tried re-seating the RAM, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after replacing the power button board on my hp g56 after water damage. Seems one of my ram chips got knocked when I was messing in the innards and became unseated. Reseated ram...laptop booted.

To clarify, laptop beeped 15 times on pressing power button, fan turned on, hard drive spun up,  wifi light stayed orange, screen blank and caps lock flashing. Whole lit of wooha for unseated ram!

Answer (score 0):

15 beeps? Are you sure there is no pause in between possible sets of beeps? I'm certain there is no beep that is 15 long.

The other comments are good. What you should also be aware of is that the hp dv6 series laptop are incredibly notorious for their graphics chips overheating, causing the solder to soften, resulting in a slight separation from the motherboard. This is not visible to the naked eye. This is caused in a design flaw by HP, the video chip is too close to the processor without enhanced cooling.

The symptoms of this problem vary from laptop to laptop. But generally they begin with the wifi card having problems, the unit rapidly becomes very slow, then eventually they may result in the unit not POSTing, no video (although possible power to backlights), possible beep codes.

The most important thing you should do right now is nail down those beep codes. HP has beep codes which translate to video problems. Everything you need to know is in those beep codes. Listen for breaks. They might be about 1 second long.

Answer (score 0):

The only record I could find of any standard POST code having a total of 15 beeps is for a Phoenix BIOS that I don't believe applies to your laptop.  It's for older computers, and a pattern of 3-4-4-4 beeps meant "check virus and backup reminders".  Given your symptoms, that pretty clearly isn't applicable.

The beeps could represent several concurrent things that collectively produce beeps that exceed the standard POST codes.  The system obviously has a problem, which would account for some of the POST beeps.  In addition to that, you could be hearing USB enumeration.

There is a BIOS setting that enumerates attached USB devices with a beep for each one.  If you disable that setting, the remaining POST beeps may make sense and serve a diagnostic purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a HP Pavilion G6 g1020
I open it to put thermal paste on the processor (I wasn't able to do it) and when I reassemble it, It beeps 15 times and the Caps Lock LED flashes continuously.
In my case it was simply that the RAM was released and I simply have to re-seating it and it start working

Answer (score 0):

I had this occur on my HP dv7-4053cl; 15 continuous beeps.

The fault was the RAM was not seated correctly. Reseat the RAM, remove the battery, hold the power button for 15 seconds then try to start it again.

Comment: Can you describe how you reseated the RAM? it may not be obvious to someone else. Cheers!